# Why does compiler say getElementByClass doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, dom

I was trying to code a small inventory kind of code.

```
    var dragIcon = document.getElementByClass('hover-div').createElement('img');
```

So I just created a new element inside the hover-div, and assigned it to the dragIcon variable.

In the Google Chrome developer mode section, it kept giving me an error that the method `getElementByClass` isn't a function.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a really sloppy method of assigning a new element to a variable? The weird part is, the image does get created inside the div, but apparently it doesn't get assigned to the `dragIcon` variable.

I tried really hard to look for a solution to this problem, but I didn't seem to find anything. Can you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it's `document.createElement`, and then you have to append it, as in `document.getElementsByClassName('hover-div')[0].appendChild()`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hover-div').forEach(function( el ){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    el.appendChild( img );
})
```

It's `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClass` and it returns an array.

Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).